# Incosistency between RMardkown preview and pdf output

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have this latex code in an RMarkdown file in R studio:

```
---
title: "matrix"
date: "November 2, 2016"
output:


pdf_document: default
---

$$
\mathbf{y} = \left[\begin{array}
{rrr}
y_{1,1} \\
y_{4,3} 

\end{array}\right]
\mathbf{X} = \left[\begin{array}
{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\right]
$$
```

The preview shows up fine in Rstudio:[image]
But when I knit to pdf I get this error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: \mathbf allowed only in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.88 \$\$ \mathbf{y}

pandoc: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works okay if you change to an explicit math environment:

```r
---
title: "matrix"
date: "November 2, 2016"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y} = \left[\begin{array}
{r}
y_{1,1} \\
y_{4,3} 

\end{array}\right]
\mathbf{X} = \left[\begin{array}
{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
```

except you also want to fix your array alignments, otherwise

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

(you need just `{r}` for the first, and `{rrrr}` for the second)

[image]

Comment: Do I need to change `\begin{array}` in `\begin{equation}`? Then I get the same error

Comment: No, change `$$` to `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Can you please post the full solution? I did what you said but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Dambo -- updated. Your YAML was also a little broken. What "doesn't work" for you?